# Chef server REST API

Tags: rest, chef-infra

wI'm exploring the Rest api of Chef for project purposes. I'm able to get, post and delete node/node-data. But I'm not able to execute PUT request, i.e. update the node related data on the server. Here is the screen shot of the error i get.[image]

Following is the code that is making the request. I have specified the authentication parameters properly, and they are working properly.

```
rest = Chef::REST.new(server_url, client_name, signing_key_filename)
print "Enter the node you want to edit :\n"
editnode = gets.chomp
node = rest.get_rest("/nodes/#{editnode}")
print "#{node.name}\n"
print "\t#{node.run_list}\n"
print "Now updating the node as per the parameters specified :\n"
update_node = {
"run_list" => "recipe[123]"
}
rest.put_rest("nodes/#{editnode}","update_node")
```

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Is your URL really https://googler? Also, it would be helpful to have the stacktrace in plaintext instead of a screenshot

Comment: Looks like you're coding in Ruby? Use the excellent Ridley gem instead of calling the REST API directly: https://github.com/RiotGames/ridley

Comment: @sethvargon Yeah. Actually I'm running the server on my local data centre vm, and have set this as the FQDN. + I've added the same to the hosts file on my workstation, so can access it with this name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So two issues:

1. The main problem is that you quoted `"update_node"` in the put_rest so you are sending that back as a literal, when the server expects a hash.
2. You can't just send the run list for the PUT, you need to send a full node data structure. The easiest way to do this is to modify the one you get back from the server from the GET.